# How to get the list of all booleans set to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table model named History and all its attributes are boolean.
How can I select only the attributes set to true?

I tried

```
History.select {|h| h == true}
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *all* ones with all true:

```
boolean_columns = Model.columns.map(&:name) - %w(id created_at updated_at)
Model.where(boolean_columns.zip([true].cycle).to_h)
```

Attributes only works on an instance, and in that case you probably just want to query it.

For a single one:

```
Model.first.attributes.select { |_, v| v == true }
```

The reason I do `v == true` instead of `v` is because you want explicit boolean true, not necessarily truthy.

Comment: what does the | _,  | do ?

Comment: Habit, it basically says I don't care about this param. In this case it's the key of the hash of attributes